# Animation using startOffset goes reversed

Tags: android, android-animation, interpolation

I created the following animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator"
     >
  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="0"
      android:toXDelta="100%p"
      android:duration="500"
     />
  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
      android:toXDelta="0"
      android:startOffset="500"
      android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

I test it on an Android 2.3.6 phone and the animation goes sequentially but REVERSED.
First it goes from left to the middle then from the middle to the right. How can I play it in the correct order?

Comment: maybe its the highest time for my solution with custom interpolator?

Comment: I tried to find some viable example but couldn't really find where a custom interpolator was used. Can you point me to a right one?

Comment: just call animation.setInterpolator(myCusromInterpolator) where custom interpolator uses the formula of sin(input*2*PI)

Comment: I added a Fade In - Fade out animation, and they are also reversed. What can I do to make the play in the correct order?

Comment: the order is detetmined by startOffset attribute or setStartOffset() method

Comment: If I set the starOffset to 500, the left->middle animation should start after 500 ms. My animation is started to the right and then jumps to the left and then to the middle. Can you check this XML with a widget?

Comment: this is because you pass wrong values to x0 and x1 parameters, but if you insist to use it instead of one custom interpolator...

Comment: What is wrong with the parameters?

Comment: first of all they are out of sense.0->100 and -100->0, it would more natural if you set them 0->100 and 100->0

Comment: They represent the width of the screen, if I change -100%p to 100%p, the widget goes out of the screen. I tried your Interpolator, it goes like a "circle", but the widget is visible when it should be "behind" the screen. Any ide for that?

Comment: probably you should set x1 to (screenWidth-widgetWidth) / 2

Comment: Then it just moves in a very little "circle". I'd like to accomplish the following movement (the big rectangle is the screen, the little one is my ImageView): http://s14.postimg.org/hk5gg2q35/animation_1.png Can it be done with an interpolator?

Comment: New TranslateAnimation(0, x1, 0, 0) where x1 is (screenwidth+widgetwidth)/2

Comment: It doesn't calculate with the Y axis, so after it moves to the right edge, it comes back to the left in front of the screen. I'd like it to be "invisible" when going from right to left. Any idea?

Comment: yes, change the interpolator from sine into two lines

Comment: How can it be done? Is there a formula for it?

Comment: change the green interpolator to red one: http://postimg.org/image/lnp58y59l/

Comment: I figured that but couldn't find out the lines' equations so I abandoned the interpolator for now. Thanks for all the good suggestions :)

Comment: man its a base math if input < .5 return 2*input else return 2*input-2

Comment: Thanks, but I chose an overshoot animation that looks better and more impulsive.

Comment: so what stops you with combining those two interpolators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't modify their orders, I eventually created two separate animations and used an AnimationListener to start the second one.

Comment: the order was ok, you just passed wrong params to your animations, now you choosed the worst solution

Comment: With each animation? Even the fade animation that has nothing to do with location parameters? :) I don't think so.

Comment: but i do think so, did you try fillEnabled=true and fillBefore=fillAfter=false ?

Comment: I tried each combinations. There were very awkward animations and the best among them was the aforementioned reversed animation. I presume it as a 2.3 bug, as there are many bugs related to Animation, like this one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17662

Comment: just tested on 2.3, runs with no problem when fillAfter=fillBefore=false and fillEnabled=true, want sample code?

Answer (score 1):

```
final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.layer0);
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        float x = (iv.getWidth() + b.getWidth()) / 2;
        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
        set.setFillBefore(false);

        Animation a;

        a = new TranslateAnimation(0, x, 0, 0);
        a.setDuration(500);
        a.setFillAfter(false);
        a.setFillBefore(false);
        a.setFillEnabled(true);
        set.addAnimation(a);

        a = new TranslateAnimation(-x, 0, 0, 0);
        a.setStartOffset(500);
        a.setDuration(500);
        a.setFillAfter(false);
        a.setFillBefore(false);
        a.setFillEnabled(true);
        set.addAnimation(a);

        iv.startAnimation(set);
    }
};
iv.setOnClickListener(l);
setContentView(iv);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply adding a set attribute element   `android:repeatMode="reverse"`. Thus your code should be..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator"
     android:repeatMode="reverse"
     >
  <translate
      android:repeatCount="infinite"
      android:fromXDelta="0"
      android:toXDelta="100%p"
      android:duration="2500"

     />
 <!--  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
      android:toXDelta="0"
      android:startOffset="500"
      android:duration="500"/> -->
</set>
```